# How can find out how much space I'll save with NTFS compression before compressing?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ntfs, compression

Is there a way to estimate how much space I would save by compressing a folder with NTFS compression without actually compressing the folder?

This is on a Windows 2008 R2 server in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

There are apparently some tools that will do it (but it was a Google search, and I'd be nervous downloading many of them).  I would personally pick a small selection of 'representative' files, stick them somewhere else, compress them, and use that ratio as an estimate.